# Quicksort algorithm Python error

Tags: python, quicksort

I am trying to implement Quicksort using Python.
This is my code:

```
import random

def quickSort(lst):
    randomIndex = random.randint(0,len(lst)-1)
    pivot = lst[randomIndex]
    greater = []
    less = []
    equal = []
    if len(lst) > 1:
        for num in lst:
            if num > pivot:
                greater.append(num)
            elif num == pivot:
                equal.append(num)
            else:
                less.append(num)
        return quickSort(less)+equal+quickSort(greater)
    else:
        return lst

def main():
    lst = [1000000,100000,1000,10000,100,10]
    sortedLst = quickSort(lst)
    print("Quicksorted List: ", sortedLst)

main()
```

How come when I run my code, it says that it runs into this error:

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

Comment: error is pretty self-explonatory. You call random on empty range, thus at some point your code calls quicksort([]), and you try to get randomIndex/pivot even when the list is empty

Comment: It's most likely because either `greater` or `less` has one element in them. So when you set `randomIndex` to be a range from 0 to the length of the list, you get `random.randint(0, 0)`. I'd recommend adding a `print` command before your `return` statement to see what those lists look like.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is that you try to select randomIndex even, when `lst` is empty, just move your initializations into `if` condition where you are sure that they are non empty

```
import random

def quickSort(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        randomIndex = random.randint(0,len(lst)-1)
        pivot = lst[randomIndex]
        greater = []
        less = []
        equal = []
        for num in lst:
            if num > pivot:
                greater.append(num)
            elif num == pivot:
                equal.append(num)
            else:
                less.append(num)
        return quickSort(less)+equal+quickSort(greater)
    else:
        return lst

def main():
    lst = [1000000,100000,1000,10000,100,10]
    sortedLst = quickSort(lst)
    print("Quicksorted List: ", sortedLst)

main()
```